# I have to delete a line: "\n run 120" from all files within a dir. How?

Tags: bash, sed

`\n` in `\n run 120` is not a newline, but a literal.
I tried the following:

```
sed -i '/(\n run 120)/d' *  
sed -i '/(\n run 120)$/d' * 
sed -i '/"\n run 120"/d' *
```

But none of the above work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
sed -i '/\\n run 120/d' *
```

Answer (score 1):

try 
     \\n ?
(hint: [quoting in Bash](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting))